# comparing DateTime value in formula

Tags: formula, formula-field

I am trying to create a formula field to set a DateTime value, but it fails with the following error:

Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'IF()'. Expected Number, received DateTime

The formula I am trying to construct is as follows:

```
IF(MQL_Date__c < First_Sales_Activity_Logged__c, First_Sales_Activity_Logged__c-MQL_Date__c, MQL_Date__c)


MQL_Date__c - Date/Time
First_Sales_Activity_Logged__c - Date/Time
Formula Field - Date/Time
```

Only if MQL_Date__c is less than First_Sales_Activity_Logged__c than set the formula value to First_Sales_Activity_Logged__c-MQL_Date__c else MQL_Date__c

Comment: what is the return type of your formula field? Is it a date? Or a Number?

Comment: your formula does not make so much sense. One parameter of the IF function, you are returning a date, in the other, you are returning the operation minus between two dates....

Comment: When you say, your formula value should be `First_Sales_Activity_Logged__c-MQL_Date__c`, what do you mean by that ? Do you need the difference between dates ?

Comment: Formula DataType is Date/Time. The Data type of all the fields used in the expression is Date/Time. MQL_Date__c - Date/Time First_Sales_Activity_Logged__c - Date/Time

Comment: @VijayGanji yes the difference between the two Date/Time fields, First_Sales_Activity_Logged__c and MQL_Date__c

Comment: @mPeixoto Currently I am setting the else value to MQL_Date__c since I was trying to see if my Date/Time formula works. But in the ideal case, it should be set to no value.

Comment: @nevrekar_amey Would you please **[edit]** your question to include all of this information?

Comment: @DavidReed All the information is in the question, there is nothing more to add. I have edited it to make the data types for the fields more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot return a `DateTime` by subtracting two `DateTime` fields, it will always return you the difference in number of days.

Also, your formula should return the value of same type in all the conditions, i.e. in your case, it is returning `Integer` in one case and `DateTime` in another case which is incorrect.

If you want to display the difference between two `DateTime` fields, you will have to change your formula return type to either `Number` or `Text` and show the difference.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the help here.